# The magnitude of the cross product of 2 vectors given in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

There is a formula for calculating the magnitude of cross product of 2 vectors in Cartesian coordinates with z = 0:

```
cross_product(v1, v2) = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x
```

Now I have the angle `theta` and the distance `r` for each vector in polar coordinates. Is there any formula for calculating the magnitude of cross product of 2 vectors in Spherical/Cylindric coordinates with z = 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put some thought into it. We can just replace `x` by `r * cos(theta)` and `y` by `r * sin(theta)`. That yields

```
cross_product(v1, v2) = v1.r * cos(v1.theta) * v2.r * sin(v2.theta) - v1.r * sin(v1.theta) * v2.r * cos(v2.theta)
```

or

```
cross_product(v1, v2) = v1.r * v2.r * sin(v2.theta - v1.theta)
```